# How do I import templates from another stylesheet?

Tags: xml, xslt, import, stylesheet

I know I have to use the `xsl:import` but I don't know how do I call the `name` of the templates.

How do I do it?

Comment: when you import another xslt in file than it will automatically apply for your conversion.

Comment: Your question is not clear. When you use `xsl:import`, **all** the templates in the imported stylesheet are imported. You then call or apply them as if they were a part of your own stylesheet. For more, read: http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2000/11/01/xslt/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using [`<xsl:import>`](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ref_xsl_el_import.asp) applying `<xsl:call-template>` is quite easy:

Sample XML named `f.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <a>abc</a>
    <b>cde</b>
</root>
```

Main sample XSLT `f.xslt`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:import href="f1.xslt"/>

 <xsl:template match="/root">
   A: <xsl:value-of select="a/text()" />
   <xsl:call-template name="secondTemplate" />
 </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Include sample XSLT `f1.xslt`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

 <xsl:template name="secondTemplate">
   B: <xsl:value-of select="b/text()" />
 </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

   A: abc
   B: cde
```

So the first XSLT(`f.xslt`) does call the second XSLT(`f1.xslt`) - which is imported with `<xsl:import ...>` - via a named template which is accessed with the `<xsl:call-template name="secondTemplate" />` line.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `<xsl:call-template>` for calling a function in a traditional programming language.

You can define functions in XSLT, like this simple one that outputs a string.

```
<xsl:template name="dosomething">
  <xsl:text>A function that does something</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
```

This function can be called via `<xsl:call-template name="dosomething">`.

Comment: Yes, but I have a ton of templates already done in a XSLT file and I want to import them to another XSLT file, so I can reuse them. 
I don't know how to do it... I know that I have to use the `xsl:import` but don't know how to call the templates afterwards.

Comment: you don't need to import all of them, importing the on upstream file is enough.